# Find the norm of a linear functional in $L^2[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Define the linear functional $f : L^2[0,1] \text{(As completion of $C[0,1]$, all the continuous complex-valued function )} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ by 
$$f(\psi)=3\int_{0}^{1}\psi(t)dt + i\int_{0}^{1} \psi(t)\sin(\pi t)\cos(\pi t)dt.$$

I have made use of Cauchy Schwarz to set a bound of $\|f\| \leq 3+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}}$, yet I can not figure out what to substitute to obtain the norm. Can I get a small hint? Thanks!

Comment: Try writing it as $f(\psi) = \langle \psi, g\rangle$ for some function $g$. Then find $\|g\|_2$.

Comment: always forget such representation.. thanks and solved ;)

Comment: @KennethNg: In this case you might want to add your solution as an answer for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @KennethNg, using Riesz representation, and writing $f(\psi)$ as $\langle\psi,(3+i\sin(\pi t)\cos(\pi t)\rangle$, we get $$\|f\|=\|3+i\sin(\pi t)\cos(\pi t)\|=\int_0^13+\frac{i\sin(2\pi t)}{2}dt=3$$